# GCP 'Query Insights' 'UTILITY COMMAND' costs

Tags: postgresql, performance, google-cloud-platform, monitoring

Postgres 12.8 cluster(1 writer, 1 reader)  hosted on GCP.

When ever I got CPU spike 'On READER instance' and dig-in 'Query Insights' for costly quires, every time most costly operation is 'UTILITY COMMAND'.

I search for 'UTILITY COMMAND' and only got [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/using-query-insights#:%7E:text=Queries%20labeled%20UTILITY%20COMMAND%20usually%20include%20BEGIN%2C%20COMMIT%2C%20and%20EXPLAIN%20commands%20or%20wrapper%20commands.)

Can someone guide me how to dig inside 'UTILITY COMMAND' and how to make it less costly on READER instance?

Wishes

Comment: Can you share the SKU that you have or a screen capture of your billing with that entry (and the associated discount, if any)?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere C18F-7FE0-0717 no discount / promotion

Comment: If it has heavy IO and CPU wait then it could be a backup job.

Answer (score 2):

This question was posted long time ago. Since it is hard to get information about `UTILITY COMMAND` in Google Cloud SQL query insights, I am gonna post an answer.
Based on Google technical support:

"
The `UTILITY COMMAND` is a classification for all queries not defined as `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, or `DELETE`, in Query Insights.

This `UTILITY COMMAND` also includes maintenance operations like `VACUUM` and table commands like `CREATE`, `DROP`, and `COPY`.

So this is not an issue to be avoided, this is a group of different queries instead of the ones shown above and maintenance operations, all in just one place.
"

I found this on a GitHub thread on an issue [here](https://github.com/concourse/concourse/issues/6589#issuecomment-871525254).

Since Cloud SQL is a managed services by Google, I guess there is not much that we can do to reduce its cost.